# Python : Allowing methods not specifically defined to be called ala __getattr__

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm trying to write a Python class that has the ability to do the following:

```
c = MyClass()
a = c.A("a name for A") # Calls internally c.create("A", "a name for A")
b = c.B("a name for B") # Calls internally c.create("B", "a name for B")
```

A and B could be anything (well, they're defined in a database, but I don't want to explicitly define them in my code)

A hacky workaround for it would be to do the following:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.createItem = ""

    def create(self, itemType, itemName):
        print "Creating item %s with name %s" % (itemType, itemName)

    def create_wrapper(self, name):
        self.create(self.createItem, name)

    def __getattr__(self, attrName):
        self.createItem = attrName
        return self.create_wrapper
```

This will work when the user calls something like:

```
a = c.A("nameA")
b = c.B("nameB")
```

However, it will fall over in situations where the function pointers are stored without being called:

```
aFunc = c.A
bFunc = c.B
aFunc("nameA") # Is actually calling c.create("B", "nameA"),
               # as c.B was the last __getattr__() call
bFunc("nameB")
```

Any suggestions for anything I'm missing here?

Thanks

Edit: I appear to have just figured this one out, but Philipp has a far more elegant solution....

My solution was:

```
class MyClassCreator():
    def __init__(self, origClass, itemType):
        self.origClass = origClass
        self.itemType = itemType

    def create_wrapper(self, name):
        return self.origClass.create(self.itemType, name)

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.createItem = ""

    def create(self, itemType, itemName):
        print "Creating item %s with name %s" % (itemType, itemName)

    def __getattr__(self, attrName):
        return MyClassCreator(self, attrName).create_wrapper
```

The version that I actually ended up using (as I needed more complexity than a single argument) is: (I don't know if this can be done using a lambda function...)

```
def __getattr__(self, attrName):
    def find_entity_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return self.find_entity(attrName, *args, **kwargs)

    return find_entity_wrapper
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement a `Mock` library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have `__getattr__` return a local wrapper function:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def create(self, itemType, itemName):
        print "Creating item %s with name %s" % (itemType, itemName)

    def __getattr__(self, attrName):
        def create_wrapper(name):
            self.create(attrName, name)
        return create_wrapper
```

There are other ways to create the wrapper function. The simplest one in this case is to use `functools.partial`:

```
import functools

class MyClass(object):
    def create(self, itemType, itemName, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Creating item %s with name %s, args %r and kwargs %r" % (itemType, itemName, args, kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, attrName):
        return functools.partial(self.create, attrName)

c = MyClass()
bFunc = c.B
bFunc("nameB", 1, 2, foo=3)
```

This will automatically pass all remaining args to the wrapped function.

Comment: I'm not sure which of yours and Ned's solutions I like best, but they are both far nicer than the one that I came up with (see the edited bottom of my question above)

Comment: They are not too different—my version is just the spelled-out variant of the lambda version. Lambdas are sometimes frowned upon in Python for being restrictive and harder to read, but semantically they are equivalent to named functions. Usually I use lambdas and other functional-like constructs only for simple expressions that don't modify state.

Comment: I've put the actual function that I ended up using at the bottom of my question - I actually needed to be able to pass through any number of arguments, which I'm not sure would work with a lambda function...

Answer (score 6):

You can get what you want by simplifying:

```
class MyClass():

    def create(self, itemType, itemName):
        print "Creating item %s with name %s" % (itemType, itemName)

    def __getattr__(self, attrName):
        return lambda x: self.create(attrName, x)

c = MyClass()
a = c.A("nameA")
b = c.B("nameB")


af = c.A
bf = c.B
af("nameA")
bf("nameB")
```

prints:

```
Creating item A with name nameA
Creating item B with name nameB
Creating item A with name nameA
Creating item B with name nameB
```

Comment: Thanks - that looks wonderfully elegant! I've never got my head around lambda before - maybe now should be the time to do that... I'll either go this way or the way that Philipp suggested... Either way works for me!

Thanks

Comment: Actually, the example in my question was a very simplified one - I actually need to be able to pass through a variable (kwargs) number of arguments, and I believe that I can't do that with lambda... Not sure, but it's good to see that Philipp's solution will happily support that.

Thanks again.