# Python: edit child methods for objects contained in child object

Tags: python, inheritance, methods

I apologize for the title...couldn't think of anything else. I have 2 classes as follows:

```
class Widget:
    def __init__(self):
        widgets.add(self)

    def remove(self):
        widgets_to_remove.add(self)

    def update(self, events, mouse_pos):
        pass

    def draw(self, screen):
        pass


class Widget_bundle(Widget):
    def __init__(self, widget_group):
        Widget.__init__(self)
        self.widget_group = widget_group # list containing objects inheriting from Widget
        self.call_for_all("remove")

    def call_for_all(self, func, *args):
        for w in self.widget_group:
            getattr(w, func)(*args)
```

the code works but I would like it if there was a way to call a method defined by a `Widget` object on a `Widget_bundle` object and have that method called by all objects in `widget_group`.  The obvious solution is to make a method for EVERY SINGLE POSSIBLE METHOD and use a for loop to iterate over the objects, or use my `call_for_all method`, which requires the function as a string and complicates other parts of the code I didn't include.  Is there a third solution?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is the context of the question? What does the calling code look like?

Comment: For example: I also have a function that updates and draws all Widget objects.  Rather than writing methods for Widget_bundle update() and draw(), which would just iterate over Widget objects and call w.update() and w.draw(), I would like undefined methods called by Widget_bundle objects to be forwarded to the Widget instances stored in widget group.

Comment: If it would help, the Widget objects are used in a Pygame GUI.  Some other objects I have made so far include label, button, and text box objects which inherit from Widget.  The Widget_bundle will be useful in creating a vertical list of labels with corresponding buttons.  This information is somewhat irrelevant, however, I provided it to help you better orient yourself with the classes I provided code for.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is your situation:

You have a class `Widget_bundle` that has a property `Widget_bundle.widget_group`. That property is a list of classes `Widget`.

You want to make a call, for example, `Widget_bundle.remove()` and translate that to a call `Widget.remove()` for each `Widget` in `Widget_bundle.widget_group`.

One way to approach this would be to customise the `Widget_bundle.__getattr__` method.

```
class Widget_bundle(Widget):

    def __init__(self, widget_group):
        Widget.__init__(self)
        self.widget_group = widget_group

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        def _bundle_helper(*args, **kwargs):
            for widget in self.widget_group:
                getattr(widget, attr)(*args, **kwargs)

        return _bundle_helper
```

Or using `functools`:

```
import functools


class Widget_bundle(Widget):

    def __init__(self, widget_group):
        Widget.__init__(self)
        self.widget_group = widget_group

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return functools.partial(self._bundle_helper, attr)

    def _bundle_helper(self, attr, *args, **kwargs):
        for widget in self.widget_group:
            getattr(widget, attr)(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now you can call `Widget_bundle.remove()`.

I referred to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434938/python-allowing-methods-not-specifically-defined-to-be-called-ala-getattr).

Comment: I think your first solution is working, however the Widget_bundle instance is trying to make calls to built-in functions such as __hash__() and __eq__().  These calls are consistently causing errors:

Comment: getattr(widget, attr)(*args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: Widget instance has no attribute '__hash__'